# Function returning object, but getting 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and want to create a function that receives a given IP address and returns some information about it

```
function getDadoIP(IP){
  var APIKey = 'key';
  var format = 'json';
  var url = 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=' + APIKey + '&ip=' + IP + '&format=' + format + '&callback=?';
  var resposta = $.getJSON(url); 

  resposta.then(function (res) {
    var info = '';

    for (var chave in res) {
      info += res[chave] + ',';
    }
    console.log(info);
    var dado = info.split(/,/);

    return {
      "codigoStatus": dado[0],
      "codigoMensagem": dado[1],
      "ipPesquisado": dado[2],
      "codigoPais": dado[3],
      "pais": dado[4],
      "regiao": dado[5],
      "cidade": dado[6],
      "codigoZip": dado[7],
      "latitude": dado[8],
      "longitude": dado[9],
      "fusoHorario": dado[10]
    };
  });
}

function setup() {
  var dados = getDadoIP('IP-goes-here');
  console.log(dados);
}
```

I am able to get the inormation I want in the function, as `console.log(info)` displays what I expected. However, the returned value is `undenfined`, as evidenced by `console.log(dados)`. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Ask yourself the question: "_Which_ function is returning something?", then look for all instances of `function`.  Then go read up about async javascript :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no return statement inside of `getDadoIP`, so it's implicitly returning undefined. You'll need to return the promise object, and then use it's `.then` method to access the final value.

```
 function getDadoIP(IP){
   var APIKey = 'key';
   var format = 'json';
   var url = 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=' + APIKey + '&ip=' +      IP + '&format=' + format + '&callback=?';
   var resposta = $.getJSON(url); 

   //** Added return statement
   return resposta.then(function (res) {
     var info = '';

     for (var chave in res) {
       info += res[chave] + ',';
     }
     console.log(info);
     var dado = info.split(/,/);

     return {
       "codigoStatus": dado[0],
       "codigoMensagem": dado[1],
       "ipPesquisado": dado[2],
       "codigoPais": dado[3],
       "pais": dado[4],
       "regiao": dado[5],
       "cidade": dado[6],
       "codigoZip": dado[7],
       "latitude": dado[8],
       "longitude": dado[9],
       "fusoHorario": dado[10]
     };
   });
 }

 function setup() {
   //** added .then
   getDadoIP('IP-goes-here')
     .then(function (dados) {
       console.log(dados);
     });
  }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With async/await:

```
async function getDadoIP(IP){
  var APIKey = 'key';
  var format = 'json';
  var url = 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=' + APIKey + '&ip=' + IP + '&format=' + format + '&callback=?';
  var res = await $.getJSON(url); 

  var info = '';

  for (var chave in res) {
    info += res[chave] + ',';
  }
  console.log(info);
  var dado = info.split(/,/);

  return {
    "codigoStatus": dado[0],
    "codigoMensagem": dado[1],
    "ipPesquisado": dado[2],
    "codigoPais": dado[3],
    "pais": dado[4],
    "regiao": dado[5],
    "cidade": dado[6],
    "codigoZip": dado[7],
    "latitude": dado[8],
    "longitude": dado[9],
    "fusoHorario": dado[10]
  };
}

async function setup() {
  var dados = await getDadoIP('IP-goes-here');
  console.log(dados);
}
```